# Sound Recorder does not show "record as" option

Tags: sound, lubuntu, microphone, audio-recording, sound-recorder

I am setting up a Lubuntu box to install in a local classroom where people are not super tech-savvy.

I need an audio recording application for them to record things using the microphone and save in a specific folder. I have chosen Sound Recorder because Audio Recorder and Audacity are too complicated.

I have one problem; the only option in the **Record From** field is **Master** and the **Record As** field where there should be file format options (.ogg, .wav, etc.) is blank with no options.

Can anybody tell me how to actually record sound using "Sound Recorder"?

when run from terminal, when I press the record button it shows:

```
(gnome-sound-recorder:1894): GStreamer-WARNING **: Element 'gconfaudiosource' already has parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my last comment, according to [this Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/1157654) `gnome-sound-recorder` is broken and won't be fixed (it will be removed in future releases). My suggestion for your classroom is to use `audacity` or write a simple GUI wrapper for `arecord`/`parec`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this article? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AudioCapture

> ... try recording by running the following command in a terminal window:
>
> `$ arecord test.wav`
>
> and speaking into your microphone. To stop this command press Ctrl+C.

It's not the way to make Sound Recorder work, but you can simply do records without installing complicated applications.

Comment: I am sure that my microphone works, as audacity records it and plays back the sound. The problem is with sound recorder I am pretty sure, and, as mentioned, this computer will go in a local classroom, and they cannot run a terminal command every time they want to record something

Comment: @adjustingthesound "complicated" when referring to Sound Recorded is quite a stretch, as is implying that using arecord is anything else than way beyond the reach of a significant part of users.

Comment: I have similar issues: `arecord` works but neither `audacity` nor `gnome-sound-recorder` actually record.

Comment: After some search, it seems that `audacity` works (I selected the wrong input). However, according to [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/1157654), `gnome-sound-recorder` is broken and won't be fixed (it will be suppressed in future releases). My suggestion for your classroom is to use `audacity` or write a simple GUI wrapper for `arecord` (or `parec`).